# Snake Plant Wrinkles and Color Fading

Tags: watering, succulents, wilt, discoloration

I moved in February from Montreal to Toronto with my snake plant in a car (that's the first picture color and shape, the second and third picture to show the difference today).

It was doing fine until a couple of months ago where its leaves started getting wrinkly and losing color.
I was worried I over-watered it so I held back a bit in hopes it recovers, which seemingly it did as I repotted it a week ago as I felt its roots were too confined (gladly, all roots were dry and no signs of mold or mushiness) but I don't think it has been doing better.
I'm confused with everything I read online about root-rot and being pot-bound but they were really all cluttered with few inches extra in diameter before repotting.
Thanks for reading and I really appreciate your help!

Ps, the white stuff in the pot in the second picture are egg shells as recommended by a friend.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your plant can use some water. It is hard with this type of plant to find the balance between overwatering or underwatering. I have some trouble with snakeplants myself too. I can recognize overwatering now, the tips of leaves get brown and the leaves get yellower/paler if overwatering continues over a longer period. If the plant gets wrinkly like your, has no brown leave tips, and the soil is dry, it just needs some more water than normal. Probably because it is growing season now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding further on answer from [benn](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/19430/benn), you need to water them more than that of your current frequency. In your second image, soil looks completely dry. You should water them once in a week depending on weather conditions and also ensure that soil doesn't become soggy. Pot should have enough number of holes in order to drain out excess water. As far as color is concerned, you should avoid direct sunlight however indirect sunlight is good for them.

In the beginning, while plant is yet to prosper and showing sign of distress, you may sprinkle water on them however be mindful that, it should be minimal.

Hope this helps.